# Segmentation fault with strcpy (ELF executable)

Tags: c, gcc

I know there is a BoF in the program, but the buffer is not exceded with "AA", then, why I obtain "segmentation fault"?...

```
$ gcc program.c -o program
$ ./program AA
Segmentation fault
```

This is the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(char *arg)
{
    char name[32];
    strcpy(name, arg);
    printf("\nWelcome, %s\n\n", name);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Use: %s YOUR_NAME\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    func(argv[2]);
    printf("The end\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dereference a null pointer. `argv[argc]` is defined as being `NULL`.

I think you meant `func( argv[1] );` . Arrays index from zero in C.

Comment: That fail! And why it wasn't appear an error for not initialize to 32 NULLS the name buffer?

Comment: Using `strcpy` with a null pointer causes undefined behaviour